# When a comments discussion is moved to chat, delete the comments from the original post

Tags: feature-request, comments, chat

Example here:

[Filters collection unavailable on *some* versions of IE9](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6987625/102937)

I've already deleted the comments that were moved, in response to a moderator flag from one of the chat participants asking that the comments be cleaned up; since not every comment was moved, I had to delete them individually.

The original comments can be seen here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2842/discussion-between-andy-e-and-matt.  The first six comments (after the feed onebox) were part of the original question.

If the purpose of the "migrate to chat" option is to reduce comment noise, a cut/paste instead of a copy/paste would be a great way to further this goal.

Comment: Don't mods get an automated flag when this happens? I thought the theory was some comments might not be relevant to the chat discussion, so a mod handles the cleanup manually

Comment: @Michael: I haven't seen such a flag.  What would it look like?

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking of the 20 comments flag

Comment: I disagree with this approach.  Leaving some comments on the original thread can serve as a "teaser" to future readers, which may prompt their interest in reading the whole discussion.  Without this, they may be much more inclined to dismiss said discussion entirely and miss out on some interesting and useful details.

Comment: Related: this can be done when a [mod manually moves comments to chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253087/can-we-improve-the-move-comments-to-chat-functionality).

Comment: Iszi -- Agree that there should be a "teaser" about what the chat is about, but the first two comments (the initial comment and the initial response from the other person) in a two-person chain are probably sufficient. Anything after that probably can get trimmed.