# Comment -> Chat migrator is a bit too greedy

Tags: bug, comments, chat, comment-replies

When migrating comments to chat recently, I had this scenario:

[image]

The first message should not have been migrated, as it was addressed to someone else.

Comment: What did I do? ;P

Comment: @Yannis You failed to warn me about future contests before me asking my question!

Comment: Off topic but since I just saw that conversation: Check out this [Meta discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2021/are-programming-related-history-trivia-questions-acceptable-on-p-se) for what trivia we considered acceptable on ProgSE. And the contest details have been in the Community Bulletin since a week before the contest (that said, quite a few people missed it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no way we could be able to tell whether that comment was already part of it or not. Consider this:

> - Just put the plaintext password into the database, that's secure enough. - *Marvin*
> - @Marvin You shouldn't use SQL, because it's not webscale. - *Ford*
> - @Ford I disagree with that; SQL is great and does all things. - *Zaphod*
> - @Zaphod You're wrong, you're thinking of jQuery. - *Ford*
> - @Ford You obviosly don't know what you're talking about. jQuery is not a database. - *Zaphod*
> - @Zaphod Ever heard of the `$.totallyWebscaleDataStore` plugin? - *Ford*

The second comment is addressed to Marvin, but it's still the beginning of the discussion between Zaphod and Ford. I argue (but admittedly it's hard to prove with data since, again, you can't really query this in an automated way) that this is the more common situation in such a case.

There also is a [request for the opposite](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133067/let-us-continue-this-discussion-in-chat-doesnt-move-the-whole-comment-thread) of what you're suggesting, namely importing *all* comments on the post to the chat room. I can see that more so than moving less, but then again it may just imported a lot of unrelated stuff.

I'm open to suggestions for improvements here, but we have to be realistic about what a computer (short of hiring Watson) is actually able to deduce, and also remember that for the continuing discussion, it's usually not vital which comments are and which are not imported.

As a side note, the question of "what comments are imported" is currently simply answered as "all comments made by those two people that were detected to have a back-and-forth".

Comment: Interestingly I used to go by Zaphod Beeblobrox on ProgSE for a while...

Comment: [The opposite of this suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133067/let-us-continue-this-discussion-in-chat-doesnt-move-the-whole-comment-thread)

Comment: @Shog9 Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Given [balpha's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133514/150214), how about the following:

### Comments Before Migration

> - Just put the plaintext password into the database, that's secure enough. - *Marvin*
> - @Marvin You shouldn't use SQL, because it's not webscale. - *Ford*
> - @Ford I disagree with that; SQL is great and does all things. - *Zaphod*
> - @Zaphod You're wrong, you're thinking of jQuery. - *Ford*
> - @Ford You obviosly don't know what you're talking about. jQuery is not a database. - *Zaphod*
> - @Zaphod Ever heard of the $.totallyWebscaleDataStore plugin? - *Ford*

### Comments After Migration

> - Just put the plaintext password into the database, that's secure enough. - *Marvin*
> - @Marvin You shouldn't use SQL, because it's not webscale. - *Ford*

### Chat Room After Migration

> - @Marvin You shouldn't use SQL, because it's not webscale. - *Ford*
> - @Ford I disagree with that; SQL is great and does all things. - *Zaphod*
> - @Zaphod You're wrong, you're thinking of jQuery. - *Ford*
> - @Ford You obviosly don't know what you're talking about. jQuery is not a database. - *Zaphod*
> - @Zaphod Ever heard of the $.totallyWebscaleDataStore plugin? - *Ford*

i.e., Ford's comment stays where it is, *and* gets migrated.

Comment: So you want to delete the comments? See [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104178/when-a-comments-discussion-is-moved-to-chat-delete-the-comments-from-the-origin). I'm still not convinced of the idea.

Comment: @balpha Ah, I've got confused, I thought they were deleted. My bad.