# Comments have already been moved to chat ....nope

Tags: bug, comments, flags, moderator-tools

Something weird happened as I was handling an auto-flag (more than 20 comments on answer) earlier today:

I clicked <kbd>Move comments to chat</kbd> and okayed the prompt to also delete the comments, and then moved on with my life and ordered my McDonald's.

Then a fellow moderator ping'd me in chat to let me know that the comments were *still* there. I figured it could have been a mobile hiccup (did it from my mobile browser after all), so I went back to the post and saw that the 20-some comments were indeed still under the flagged answer (the flag hadn't been cleared?!), so I clicked that <kbd>Move comments to chat</kbd> button again (this time from a desktop browser), and got this message:

[image: comments have already been moved to chat .....nope]

The comment/link to the chatroom had been added, but the comments lingered under the post, and the only way to actually clear the flag was to click <kbd>No action needed...</kbd> and dismiss the flag as useful.

I swear I've seen this actually work before (i.e. "move comments to chat" actually *moves* the comments to chat), so what happened?

---

[Can we improve the Move Comments to Chat functionality?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253087) is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), so if the intent was to actually improve that **flag handling tool**, then it should behave the same way as the **mod menu option**, and it doesn't.

Comment: I've seen this as well. You have to go back and purge all the comments and then undelete the one pointing to chat if this happens.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we improve the Move Comments to Chat functionality?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253087/can-we-improve-the-move-comments-to-chat-functionality)

Comment: @terdon sure.. except that one says "status-completed" - so if it's asking the same thing, then there *is* a bug.

Comment: Yeah, leaving open because that other one is supposed to be [status-completed].

Comment: As far as I recall, the status-completed was added because the mod tool was created. Before that, we could only move comments to chat if a flag was raised and we then had to delete them manually. We can now do it directly from the mod menu and avoid the issue. I agree that it would be even better to have the flag button act like the mod menu but perhaps you could edit you question to reflect that?

Answer (score 3):

Uhm. This is normal as far as I know. Before the [recently added](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239513/203101) mod->move to chat functionality, you had to:

1. Click on move comments to chat in the flag UI (comments were *copied* to chat, not moved).
2. Go to mod-> purge comments which deleted the comments.
3. Scroll down and undelete the autocomment about moving to chat
4. Dismiss the flag as helpful.

So what you describe is what I've always seen. Could you be thinking of the new mod -> move to chat that we now have in the mod menu which does actually *move* instead of copying and which doesn't even require the flag anymore?

Comment: That makes sense now. Another occurrence of the same thing working differently depending on where you run it from.

Comment: @DavidPostill it isn't actually the same thing. We got the fancy "move comments to chat" flag first and didn't get the actually functional mod -> move to chat option until a while later.

Comment: Well it should work the same from both places :)

Comment: Aye, that it should indeed.

Answer (score 3):

@terdon has excellently answered already, as have the comments, but if you want to automatically delete the comments, you'll just have to go to the actual post, rather than handling the flag from the diamond mod flag menu.

When you move comments to chat from the mod menu *on the post*, you have the option of actually *moving* them, or of simply moving the *conversation* to chat, leaving the comments there.  When you click on your mod menu, you see the option to move comments to chat.  When you click on the radio button, you should see something like this:

[image]

If you want to *delete* the comments from the post as well, you need to check the checkbox underneath which says, "Also delete the moved comments from the post."

Comment: I still consider this a bug. It doesn't work as advertised.

Comment: @Meta'sMug, fair enough.  We'll see if the team does something about it.

Comment: Aye, in 6-8 weeks ;-)